# How to add a third party jar to Maven central

Tags: maven, grails, jar

I have a few jars which I have downloaded and kept in the `lib` folder of a grails project.
Now I need to download third-party jars from maven.

For example `JRI.jar`, which is a third-party jar, until now I have downloaded and kept in the grails project's `lib` folder.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.nuiton.thirdparty</groupId>
  <artifactId>JRI</artifactId>
  <version>0.9-6</version>
</dependency>
```

I have found this [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.nuiton.thirdparty/JRI/0.9-6) but I am not using `pom.xml` to specify. I need to specify it in grails `BuildConfig.groovy` file.

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Nice edit by @PaulRoub. awesome...

Comment: I don't think the recent edit was a good idea. Specifying a Grails dependency and uploading an artifact to one of who knows how many maven repos are two very different questions.

Comment: Read all comments of Answer if someone getting trouble to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For *BuildConfig.groovy* you can use the Gradle format: **'org.nuiton.thirdparty:JRI:0.9-6'**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.nuiton.thirdparty:JRI:0.9-6'
}
```

Comment: Hi @EmmanuelRosa csvjdbc-1.0-22.jar do you know maven gradle for this specific jar with same version.

Comment: I could not find that version in a maven repository. I only found 1.0.9 http://repository.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo/net/sourceforge/csvjdbc/csvjdbc/ You can file a bug asking to get the latest version uploaded to a maven repo.

Comment: compile('org.log4mongo:log4mongo-java:0.7.4') do you have any idea about it. where should I keep this in dependency block or plugins block. it has any dependency. its not working, thank you

Comment: It's not a Grails plugin so it should be `runtime('org.log4mongo:log4mongo-java:0.7.4')` in the dependency block. Then you have to configure the log appender: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.1/guide/conf.html#logging

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers @EmmanuelRosa. when I try  runtime('org.log4mongo:log4mongo-java:0.7.4') its giving error. like one other module used outside of grails application and when I use  build('org.log4mongo:log4mongo-java:0.7.4') its giving log4j:ERROR Error initializing log4j: org/log4mongo/MongoDbAppender
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/log4mongo/MongoDbAppender

Comment: Well it should be runtime. What is the exact error you get when using runtime?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [com.project.projectname.modulename.Module] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly

Comment: And where the jar will be placed after download

Comment: The jar ends up in `~/.m2/repository/`. What does your log appender configuration look like?

Comment: For build('org.log4mongo:log4mongo-java:0.7.4') its giving log4j:ERROR Error initializing log4j: org/log4mongo/MongoDbAppender java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/log4mongo/MongoDbAppender and not for  runtime('org.log4mongo:log4mongo-java:0.7.4') see comment starts with "Thanks"

Comment: Sorry but now I am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/AggregationOptions on runtime('org.log4mongo:log4mongo-java:0.7.4') and runtime('org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.10.1')

Comment: runtime('org.log4mongo:log4mongo-java:0.7.4'){
          excludes 'mongo-java-driver'
} Worked this for me no errors now. Thanks @EmmanuelRosa for your help throughout.